# Determine whether the following ideals are prime in $Z[i][x][y]$, if they are not maximal give a maximal ideal containing it.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The ideals:

$(x,y)$ I think that it is a prime ideal, however, not a maximal. It is prime as $Z[i]$ is an integral domain. It is contained $(3,x,y)$ which is maximal as $Z_3[i]$ is a field.

$(x,2y)$ is not prime as it does not contain $2$ or $y$. $(3,x,y)$ contains it.

$(x^2+1,y)$ is not prime as it does not contain $x-i$ or $x+i$. $(3,x-i,y)$ contains it and is maximal as the quotient is isomorphic to $Z_3[i]$

$(3,x^2+1,y)$ is not prime as it does not contain $x-i$ or $x+i$. $(3,x-i,y)$ contains it and is maximal as the quotient is isomorphic to $Z_3[i]$

$(5,x^2+1,y)$ is not prime as it does not contain $x-i$ or $x+i$.I think $(5,2+i,x+i,y)$ is a maximal ideal  that contains it.

Is all of this correct?

Comment: Are there any that you are unsure about and/or any concrete things you think might need further justification? Why is the ideal $(5, 2+i, x+i, y)$ maximal?

Comment: @roxas3582 Just wan to to see if I am correct. $(5,2+i,x+i,y)$ is maximal as $Z[i]/(5,2+i)$ is a field say $F$, then the quotient ring is $F[x][y]/(x-i,y)\approx F[x]/(x+i)\approx F$

Comment: If an ideal isn't prime, it isn't maximal either?

Comment: These are all correct, but it is possible to be sceptical about some of the answers. For instance it may seem obvious that $2$ and $y$ are not elements of $(x,2y)$, but could you prove that?

Comment: Since $5 = (2 + i)(2 - i)$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, it's unnecessary to write your answer to the fourth of these in the form $(5, 2 + i, x + i, y)$; we may omit the $5$ and just write $(2 + i, x + i, y)$. Similarly, $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(5, 2+i)$ is really just $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(2 + i)$. Not that these answers are *wrong*, just that they can be simplified to avoid redundancy.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I think so. 2 is actually clear as any elment of the ideal is either $0$ or a polynomail of degree at least 1. $y$ is a little bit more tricky. We could just factor $x$ out and then we only need to worry about polynomials in $y$ and the problem becomes easy. But also $x(f(x,y)+y(2g(x,y)-1)=0$ would need to be satisfied if $y$ was in the ideal consider the point $(0,1)$ it yield $2g(0,1)-1=0$ which is impossible over $Z[i]$

Comment: @RiversMcForge That is true, i knew $(5,x+i,y)$ was not maximal so i just wanted to add something that would make it maximal. I did not notice that i could get $5$ that way. Thank you!